# What happens when request.then(function(response) { } is run?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

**PROBLEM**

This:

```
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(params, valueRangeBody);
request.then(function(response) {
    ...
}
```

works when the function it is in is called from  `updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn)` but not when called from an anchor tag.

When it works, `console.log(response.result);` displays an object, but I can't tell what `console.log(response.result);` is when it doesn't work because nothing happens after `request.then(function(response)` is called.

**DETAIL**

This works:

```
    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
       if (isSignedIn) {
          nameSignIn(); 
       }
   }
```

This does not work:

```
<a href="javascript:nameSignIn();">Sign In</a>
```

Here is nameSignIn():

```
    function nameSignIn() {
  var params = {
    // The ID of the spreadsheet to update.
    spreadsheetId: '[ACTUAL ID REMOVED]',

    // The A1 notation of the values to update.
    range: 'I5',

    // How the input data should be interpreted.
    valueInputOption: 'RAW',
  };

  var valueRangeBody = {
    // All existing properties will be replaced.

    "range": "I5",  //Set this to cell want to add 'x' to.
      "majorDimension": "ROWS",
      "values": [
        [ 'x' ]
      ],          

  };

  var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(params, valueRangeBody);
  request.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.result);
  }, function(reason) {
    console.error('error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
  });
}
```

**How do I troubleshoot why nothing appears to happen after `request.then(function(response)` is run?**

This is happening in Chrome and Firefox on Win 10.  No javascript errors in dev tool's console.

See long description of problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813399/google-sheets-api-write-to-sheet-not-working-when-put-on-page-that-has-read-from)

Comment: Instead of using <a href="javascript:nameSignIn();">Sign In</a>, have you tried using a button and adding your function nameSignIn() in the onlick property?

Comment: Thank you for your reply and time noogui.  I used your suggestion and created a button to call my nameSignIn function but it is doing the same thing as when called from <a> - nothing seems to happen after request.then(function(response) gets run.